# Navigate URL but don't load images?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to navigate url, but without loading any of images on the web page. Tried this,

```
Dim ie As New Object()
ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Document.body.innerHTML = Replace(ie.Document.body.innerHTML, "<img", "<div ")
ie.Navigate2("http://www.example.org")
```

But I'm getting "Application stopped" error when I run the program. What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: FYI, you don't need `New` here

Comment: I do, otherwise, there would be errors, see > http://i.snag.gy/L66AR.jpg

Comment: Try `Dim ie As Object`

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't do that in VS2013.

Comment: In the beginning of the code, I just added "Imports System.IO" have you done something different ?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Console? Windows Forms? If it's a Windows Forms application, you would be better off dragging a WebBrowser control onto the form.

Comment: Its on vb.net, and no forms.